# Grease pencil black circles

Tags: grease-pencil

I opened my grease pencil animation today to find two black circles on the bottom  right of the drawing area. they remain there in 2d and 3d. its weird because they were not there when i saved and closed the project but they are now. they are not just drawings either as they carry over frame to frame and never move. Assuming and hoping i can just work as though they arent there and remove them later. 
Thanks[image]

Comment: Hi. Please add a picture to your post to show what you mean.

Comment: lmk if that helps

Answer (score 1):

---

I believe those are the "lookdev preview spheres" as I like to call them. They appear in the same spot as your screenshot when in the *shading* tab in a default file. In a shellnut they show some basic lighting on a default sphere, and a HDRI if set up with one. I believe they are rendering as black circles because you don't have lighting in your scene or something funky is happening with some lighting settings, leaving them as spheres of solid shadow.

These spheres **will not render** in your final output, so if you're fine with them being there, you can stop here.

However, if you want to get rid of them, you can change your rendering mode from lookdev to anything else. I haven't found a checkbox to get rid of them completely yet, but there is a setting to make them smaller. You can change the **lookdev spheres size** in the panel accessed by clicking the settings cog that appears under a dropdown menu in the top right corner of your viewport.
[image: setting screenshot]

### TL;DR: **The circles won't render, so you can ignore them, but if you want them smaller you can turn down the sphere size.**